# how to redirect inside of iframe location to another location?

Tags: javascript, iframe

How can i redirect a I-frame location to another location?
any idea?
i have this kind of sample what I'm trying to do

I want this location to another one by click button inside of that site.
when this site is logged in then when i pressed log out button I want to come back on this page but still in this I-frame.

How this is possible?

**HTML**

```
  <iframe scrolling="no" src="http://www.example.com/login">
  </iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function DoubleOpen(site1, site2) {
var site2=site2;
document.getElementById("frame").src=site1;
setTimeout(function() { loadSite(site2); },4000);
} 

function loadSite(site2){
document.getElementById("frame").src=site2;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Give an id to your iframe

```
<iframe scrolling="no" src="http://www.example.com/login" id ="myframe">
</iframe>
```

then on your button click

```
var frame = document.getElementById('myframe');
 frame.src = "your new src";
```

Comment: The problem is i cant add script on this site button. Because its not mine site. its some another website.

Comment: @Mr.beginner look bro, you would be having this iframe in a some html page than you will hav your own button apart from this ifame, whic you can control accordingly :)

Comment: I m putting this iframe into my website but the link of that site is something else which is not accessible for me to add id into that log out button.

Comment: How i can change the source by click on button? suppose i added the script on page. then how i can go to another url by clicking?